# HTML table containing JQM widgets with NO PADDING or SPACING

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

When I embed jqm widgets in a simple javascript-generated html table, it FORCES padding/spacing in each cell.  I just want a very compact JQM table with JQM widgets in it.  Is there a CSS class that I'm missing, or a jqm table attribute that will get this done? Basicall just like a cellpadding=0, cellspacing=0 table? Thanks!!!

[image: What my table looks like]

Comment: Can't tell unless we see the markup and code.  Try making a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f4EXA/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra spacing above and below the fields comes from JQuery Mobile, you can override it:

```
#myTable .ui-input-search, #myTable div.ui-input-text {
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/f4EXA/4/